# How to use MVC4 tuple with multiple list parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I did this to bind two stored procedures.

The stored procedures return table/list data.

```
var P1_PT_Pct_Thrown = pp.ppsproc_P1_PT_Pct_Thrown(_pid, _vs);
        List<ppsproc_P1_PT_Pct_Thrown_Result> ptpt = null;
        ptpt = new List<ppsproc_P1_PT_Pct_Thrown_Result>();
        ppsproc_P1_PT_Pct_Thrown_Result pt = new ppsproc_P1_PT_Pct_Thrown_Result();
        foreach (var p in P1_PT_Pct_Thrown)
        {
            pt.Years = p.Years;
            pt.FB = p.FB;
            pt.Cut = p.Cut;
            pt.CB = p.CB;
            pt.SL = p.SL;
            pt.SP_CH = p.SP_CH;
            pt.Other = p.Other;
            ptpt.Add(pt);
        }
```

This is the second table

```
var P1_PT_Pct_Thrown = pp.ppsproc_P1_PT_Pct_Thrown(_pid, _vs);
        List<ppsproc_P1_PT_Pct_Thrown_Result> ptpt = null;
        ptpt = new List<ppsproc_P1_PT_Pct_Thrown_Result>();
        ppsproc_P1_PT_Pct_Thrown_Result pt = new ppsproc_P1_PT_Pct_Thrown_Result();
        foreach (var p in P1_PT_Pct_Thrown)
        {
            pt.Years = p.Years;
            pt.FB = p.FB;
            pt.Cut = p.Cut;
            pt.CB = p.CB;
            pt.SL = p.SL;
            pt.SP_CH = p.SP_CH;
            pt.Other = p.Other;
            ptpt.Add(pt);
        }
```

Then the return

```
var tuple = new Tuple<ppsproc_P1_PT_Pct_Thrown_Result, ppsproc_P1_PE_FB_Result>(ptpt, pefb);
        return View(tuple);
```

I've got error: **ptpt** and **pefb** are invalid.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you pasted the first table twice... also it looks like you are trying to create a Tuple of List but you are actually creating a Tuple of single items. Try:

```
var tuple = new Tuple<
                     List<ppsproc_P1_PT_Pct_Thrown_Result>,
                     List<ppsproc_P1_PE_FB_Result>
                     >(ptpt, pefb);
```

This may not be what you are after, though; you might have to re-think your code and crate a `List<Tuple<ppsproc_P1_PT_Pct_Thrown_Result, ppsproc_P1_PE_FB_Result>>` then iterate through your lists to create the Tuples as pairs.